# Warning: [react-router] Location did not match any routes - only in static assets

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've found several similar issues related to this warning, but I think mine is different. My app actually runs fine with `webpack-dev-server` but breaks when I try to open the static `index.html` file that I build.

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/Users/<path>/<to>/dist/index.html" did not match any routes
```

I went ahead and created a repo with a pared-down version of the app I'm working with. I've included a link to it below:

https://github.com/samcorcos/react-router-error

To reproduce the error, run `yarn` to install the dependencies, `npm run dev` to see that the project works fine with the dev server, then `npm run build` and open the `index.html` file in `dist/` to see that react router give the error noted above.

The basic configuration is almost identical to the docs:

```
const Routes = (
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Any thoughts what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You don't just open `index.html` manually and use it, You have to run a server which serves index.html file. You can easily use `AWS S3` for hosting static apps since its a server returning your assets.

Comment: Use a hash history for static assets. If you want the clean URLs that a browser history allows, you will need a server.

Comment: @PaulS You're right, looks like changing it to `hashHistory` made it locally-runnable.

Comment: @RandomUser Good to know. I previously had it working with `hashRouter` both locally and on S3. Though, I'm curious why the root route wouldn't work. I understand that if you try to access a route like `/settings` it will break because there is no server to serve those assets, but why wouldn't the root work with the current configuration?

Comment: @samcorcos Check your error again, It says location `"/Users/<path>/<to>/dist/index.html"` didn't match any route, Its using the entire file path as the route name, Do you have any route matching that specific path? (i hope this is the case), While `hashHistory` works because its uses `#/` after filename and that makes it easy to access all the params and perform routing based on that.